# how to notify Activity from ViewModel when using PagedList in Android?

Tags: android, pagedlist, android-livedata

I have used `LivePagedListBuilder` to create `LiveData<PagedList<T>>` in my `Activity`

```
LivePagedListBuilder(DeviceDataSourceFactory(), config).build().observe(this, Observer { adapter.submitList(it) })
```

List gets generated well from `ViewModel` and there's a button in each item that will remove itself from the list

```
fun remove() {
    // additional work here
}
```

I've googled and found we can call `adapter.notifyItemRemoved()` to remove the item from the list, but only `Activity` holds the instance of `adapter`. Therefore, I need a way for `ViewModel` to tell `Activity` what needs to be done. I've tried things like

```
Observer {
    it?.forEach { item -> item.event.observe() } // where we observes the event 
    adapter.submitList(it)
}
```

but I found this block of code is only called twice no matter how much data. I guess it is called in `loadInitial` and `loadAfter` then after reference is linked, it doesn't go to the block in `Observer`.